# Accessing variables from a different directory

Tags: python, scrapy

How would I access a variable, var, that's in fileA within the

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

in a different file, fileB? I've tried:

```
import fileA    
from fileA import main
print (main.var)


import fileA
from fileA import var
print (var)

import fileA
from fileA import __name__
print (__name__.var)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want variables to be accessible when the module is imported, don't put them in

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

That `if` block is meant to explicitly hide things from those who import the module (in the main module, `__name__` is `"__main__"`, whereas in imported modules, the `__name__` is something else - the name of the module).

So, if you currently have this

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_variable = 7
    ...
```

Change it to this:

```
my_variable = 7

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```